# After upgrade ruby from 2.4.0 to 2.7.0 and RubyGem to 3.1.2 I can't install any gem on windows due to "installing into parent path is not allowed"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
C:\PROGRA~1\test-application\embedded\lib>gem install mixlib-cli --debug --verbose --backtrace --version '1.7.0'
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
HEAD https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=mixlib-cli
200 OK
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/specifications/mixlib-cli-1.7.0.gemspec
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1475 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/specifications/mixlib-cli-1.7.0.gemspec
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/mixlib-cli-1.7.0
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/mixlib-cli-1.7.0
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/mixlib-cli-1.7.0
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1475 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/mixlib-cli-1.7.0
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixl
ib-cli-1.7.0
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:492 - No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/rub
y/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Gemfile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Gemfile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Gemfile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Gemfile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1475 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Gemfile
C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Gemfile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:492 - No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/rub
y/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/LICENSE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/LICENSE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/LICENSE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/LICENSE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1475 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/LICENSE
C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/LICENSE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:492 - No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/rub
y/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/NOTICE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/NOTICE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/NOTICE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/NOTICE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1475 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/NOTICE
C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/NOTICE
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:492 - No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/rub
y/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/README.md
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/README.md
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/README.md
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/README.md
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1475 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/README.md
C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/README.md
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:492 - No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/rub
y/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Rakefile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Rakefile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Rakefile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Rakefile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1475 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Rakefile
C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/Rakefile
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:492 - No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/rub
y/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/lib
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1332 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/g
ems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1475 - No such file or directory @ apply2files - C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/
2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:519 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - C:/Program Files/test-application/embedded
/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/lib
Exception `Gem::Package::PathError' at C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:522 - installing into parent path lib/mixlib/cli.rb of C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/
embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0 is not allowed
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::PathError)
    installing into parent path lib/mixlib/cli.rb of C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0 is not allowed
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:522:in `block in mkdir_p_safe'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:516:in `each'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:516:in `reduce'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:516:in `mkdir_p_safe'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:438:in `block (2 levels) in extract_tar_gz'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:67:in `each'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:421:in `block in extract_tar_gz'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:550:in `block in open_tar_gz'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:547:in `wrap'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:547:in `open_tar_gz'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:420:in `extract_tar_gz'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:400:in `block (2 levels) in extract_files'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:67:in `each'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:397:in `block in extract_files'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:30:in `open'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:30:in `with_read_io'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/package.rb:394:in `extract_files'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/installer.rb:865:in `extract_files'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/installer.rb:325:in `install'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:93:in `install'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:195:in `block in install'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in `each'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in `install'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:208:in `install_gem'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in `block in install_gems'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:217:in `each'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:217:in `install_gems'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:165:in `execute'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/command.rb:325:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:178:in `process_args'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:148:in `run'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:59:in `run'
        C:/PROGRA~1/test-application/embedded/bin/gem.cmd:29:in `'
```

Comment: It looks like some issue with RubyGem

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use ruby inside a **docker** `docker run -it --rm --name rake-tests -v ${PWD}:/srv/rubyfiles ruby:2.6 sh`. When you remove the `--rm` parameter the container will stay and it can be reused, and you avoid re-downloading the bundle / gems everytime when you run the container.

On Windows I had always issues with `bundle` or `gems`.